# How can I make an even ground for a garden nursery, without using concrete?

Tags: floor, landscaping

I want to make a garden nursery. I know that many use concrete for this purpose but I would like to find out if there is a cheaper alternative. My requirement is simple - the ground should be even to walk on, low maintenance and it should be able to withstand the weather (I think water clogging can be handled by using the right gradient in height).

Are there any DIY options as well?

Comment: What size are you talking about?

Comment: about 1/4 acre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4" of packed gravel (tamped every 2" with a plate vibrator) will meet all your requirements: cost, DIY and drainage.  In fact, unless you are sited over clay, no slope will be needed: rain will percolate through.

If you want a more formal surface, add an inch of sand and top with pavers or flagstone.

Use a mix of crushed 3/4 gravel with fines (particles all the way down to stone dust, 21AA in my area)

Plate vibrator: [image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. This sounds like a great alternative.